# using post requests in python with parameters using the requests module

Tags: python

I have written a php script witch essentially takes parameters from post requests and sends an email based on that. I could, more easily, used python to send the email, but this project won't work as expected if that is done. The issue is not with php, as I've used it before with c++ and everything works fine. The problem comes when using python. I know I'm doing something wrong, and I have a good idea of what that is based on research, but I'm unable to find out how to fix it myself. I understand I need to be using dictionaries with data = in "requests.post" but I'm not quite sure of how one would go and do this. Here's the attempted code.

```
import requests

w=raw_input("type the email address to witch the message will be received.")
n=raw_input("name?")
s=raw_input("subject?")
m=raw_input("email message?")
if w=="" or n=="" or f=="" or m=="":
    print "Empty fields are not allowed. Now exiting."
else:
    r=requests.post("http://example.com/mailer.php?who=%s&name=%s&from=%s&sub=%s&mess=%s") % (w, n, f, s, m)
```

Comment: You could take 5 min to read the requests doc.

Comment: There is no declared an "f" variable in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Putting your data into the URL is mostly for GET requests.  A server may or may not notice it in a POST request.  Try this instead:

```
r = requests.post("http://example.com/mailer.php", data={
    'who': w, 'name': n, 'from': f, 'sub': s, 'mess': m})
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing your [`data` dictionary](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) as follows:

```
payload = {
    'who': w,
    'name': n,
    'from': f,
    'sub': s,
    'mess': m,
}

r = requests.post("http://example.com/mailer.php", data=payload)
```

Also, note that:

```
if not all((w, n, f, m)):
```

is a nicer equivelent to:

```
if w=="" or n=="" or f=="" or m=="":
```